# Does Jasmine work with Chrome Apps?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, google-chrome-app

Yes, in case you were wondering. There's no conflict with Chrome Apps' CSP restrictions, and that goes for Derick Bailey's Jasmine.Async (https://github.com/derickbailey/jasmine.async) as well.

I set up the tests in the normal way, doing nothing at all different for the Chrome App environment. To kick off the tests, I used this function, based on the conventional Jasmine-invoking examples:

```
function jasmine_run() {
    var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
    jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 1000;
    var htmlReporter = new jasmine.HtmlReporter();
    jasmineEnv.addReporter(htmlReporter);
    jasmineEnv.specFilter = function(spec) {
        return htmlReporter.specFilter(spec);
    };
    jasmineEnv.execute();
}
```

One issue I didn't solve, because I didn't care about it, is that none of the links in the output (used to run individual tests, among other things) work, because there's no navigation in Chrome Apps. However, this in no way affects the tests themselves, only a feature of the HTML display.

Nearly everything worth doing is done asynchronously in my apps, but Jasmine.Async handles that very well, as in this example (the Facebook module is my own):

```
describe('Facebook',
    function () {
        var async = new AsyncSpec(this);
        async.it("authorizes",
            function(done) {
                Facebook.authorize(
                    function(success) {
                        expect(success).toBeTruthy();
                        done();
                    }
                );
            }
        );
        async.it("searches",
            function(done) {
                Facebook.call("search?q=" + encodeURIComponent('Adolfo') +
"&type=user&fields=picture,gender,id,name,updated_time,username",
                    function (result) {
                        expect(result.data.length > 0).toBeTruthy();
                        expect(result.data[0].username).not.toBeNull();
                        done();
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
);
```

I didn't check to see if Jasmine works with Chrome extensions, as I don't write extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some info as an answer, since the question is already answered.

Some time ago I used Jasmine in app development and had no problems. I approached it slightly differently, however, which meant my output did open correctly.

Instead of running the tests in the normal app, I created a test page for running the jasmine tests. As the logic of apps is (due to CSP) separated from the HTML files, this should always be possible, and makes it even easier to keep your test code separate from your application logic.

Comment: I don't see why a test page would allow the navigation to work unless it's sandboxed, which means no access to Chrome APIs. The code I want to unit test uses those APIs. Am I missing something?

Comment: OK. I meant you run the pages outside of the app (i.e. just in a browser), but yes it means you can't use the chrome APIs, you are just testing your application logic.